# how to make another post request after one is done to stripe api from express?

Tags: node.js, express, post, stripe-payments, backend

I am trying to make a subscription to stripe, and in order for that I need a user created first - done. 
After I create the user how can i proceed automatically to make the subscription for given user?

my code so far

```
const stripe = require('./../constants/stripe');

const postStripeCharge = res => (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
  if (stripeErr) {
    res.status(500).send({
      error: stripeErr
    });
  }
  else {
    res.status(200).send({
      success: stripeRes
    });
  }
}

const paymentApi = app => {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({
      message: 'Hello Stripe checkout server!',
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString()
    })
  });

  app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('request in server', req);

    // stripe.charges.create(req.body, postStripeCharge(res));
    stripe.customers.create({
      description: 'customer for ' + req.body.email,
      source: req.body.token
    }, postStripeCharge(res))
  });

  return app;
};

module.exports = paymentApi;
```

this is the code i want to call after the user is created :

```
stripe.subscriptions.create({
          customer: req.id,
          items: [{
            plan: 'plan_CyQRCVcrEztYI7'
          }],
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it: it is not `req.body.token` but `req.body.source`, and then it works as it should.